# Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments, mern

So I am getting the error in Stripe that "Cannot charge a customer that has no active cards".
I am using node js for this

Payment Code is given below

```
try {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: req.body.email,
      source: req.body.id,
    });

    const payment = await stripe.charges.create(
      {
        amount: req.body.totalAmount * 100,
        currency: "inr",
        customer: customer.id,
        receipt_email: req.body.email,
        confirm: true,
        off_session: true,
      },
      {
        idempotencyKey: uuidv4(),
      }
    );
```

And I am getting the following error

```
type: 'StripeCardError',
  raw: {
    code: 'missing',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/missing',
    message: 'Cannot charge a customer that has no active card',
    param: 'card',
    type: 'card_error',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Log out `req.body.id` as that might be `null` and then investigate why your frontend is not passing that parameter to your backend.

Second, `confirm` and `off_session` are not supported parameters on the `/v1/charges` endpoint.